# Как получить текст из буфера при операциях cut и copy?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть задача написать компонент, который будет получать и встраивать ссылки при копировании куска текста, для защиты авторского права.
Попытался получить данные следующим образом

```
function copyHandler(e) {
 // e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", e.clipboardData+"hello");
  console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
  //e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener("copy", copyHandler, false);
```

Однако, чтобы я  не делал, данные объект. Использую я браузер chrome  57. Подскажите, как получить текст через переменную или массив